# laravel foreach in foreach

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

i was post data by ajax to controller laravel the request data is object from local storage, the data is array with 3 array multidimendional, but there only 1 data if i use dd. i want to issue that data and fill its to database but only 1 data can be out from array

```php
        $req = $request->request;
        foreach ($req as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($value as $key1 => $val) {
                dd($val['qty']);
                dd($val);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `dd()` mean `dump and die` - your script end right after the first `dd`, use `print_r()` instead

Answer (score 0):

your testing code should be...

*add break if you need

```
$req = $request->request;
if(is_array($req)) {
    foreach ($req as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            foreach ($value as $key1 => $val) {
                print_r($val['qty']);
                print_r(json_encode($val));
                print_r($val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "message": "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\MATERI\\myolshop\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\HomeController.php",
    "line": 73,
    "trace": [

Comment: @GalihAdeSaputro may be you didn't passed array in for loop... take a look to update answer...

Answer (score 0):

`dd()` in laravel returns the value and immediately exit from the code. It means it does not wait until the looping completes. So, you can use `dd()` function to the `$request->request`

```
dd($request->request);
```

If you see the multidimensional array as per your said, it means the code is right. Then you can use both the loop and store the values or pass to the blade template.